# :hover issue when mouse moves over an iframe which is inside the div | Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, html, css, iframe, hover

**Here is my problem:**

I have made a small bar in the left side of the browserwindow `#blokje{left:-180px; position:absolute;...}`, when users hover over the bar --> the position changes using `#blokje:hover{left:0};`
All this works fine, but now I've added a google adsense frame inside the div and... everything works fine except in IE (most used browser; ads...)

It looks like the div:hover disappears over the frame causing annoying flickering and users are unable to click ads !

I think that a possible solution would be to use jquery  instead of css to perform the hover effect. Can someone translate my css for me to jQuery ?

```
#blokje{width:200px; height:200px; background:#F1F1F1; position:relative; left:-180px; color:black; }
#blokje:hover{left:0;}
#blokje #tit{position:absolute; width:30px; height:200px; background:black; right:0; top:0; }
```

**fiddler** explains the issue; please note that the problem is only in IE

http://jsfiddle.net/6FeH8/

The **live example online in a test environment** not cached (Note: it's about the bar in the left not the 404 error !)

http://kramels.x10.mx/goedkoopste-autolening.tk/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should achieve the effect you want. This is based on the linked answer.
jQuery:

```
    if($.browser.msie){
        $("#blokje iframe").on("hover",function(){ 
            $(this).parents("#blokje").toggleClass("hover");
        });
    }
```

CSS:

```
#blokje:hover,#blokje.hover{left:0;}
```

Comment: I can't make it work on my live website. In the fiddle it works fine. What would be the best place to add the code. here is the live website: http://goedkoopste-autolening.tk Maybe someone experiences with other methods to achieve the same goal ?

Comment: you need to put it within your `$(function() {`, in script block right after where you have it, after the two calls to "bind". The reason is because `$(function()` causes the code inside to run after jquery is loaded.

Comment: a quick not, if anyone is having this issue with youtube's iframe embed remember to add "?wmode=transparent" to the embed url